# Custom post type single page returns 404

Tags: custom-post-types

**Edit** This has been resolved. See the cause and resolution below.

**Edit:** this may offer an important clue. When I'm logged in as the admin, the links work fine, but when I'm logged out I get the 404 error.

Before posting I tried almost every suggestion from searching StackExchange and google.

Overview: When I enter the permalink of a post it returns a 404. When I click on a link created by `get_the_permalink();` I will see a 404 and this url structure `?post_type=lunchlearn&p=530` rather than `/lunchlearn/burner-start-up-and-tech/`

I've tried saving the permalink structure, flush_rewrite_rules, different rewrite rules, etc. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

I have a few custom post types I created within the functions.php. One example is below:

```php
function register_lunchandlearn () {
  // Lunch and Learn post type
  $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Lunch and Learn',
        'singular_name' => 'Lunch and Learn',
        'add_new' => 'Add Event',
        'all_items' => 'All Events',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add Event',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Event',
        'new_item' => 'New Event',
        'view_item' => 'View Event',
        'search_item' => 'Search Events',
        'not_found' => 'No events found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No events found in trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent event'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'lunchlearn', 'with_front' => false ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions'),
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
    );
    register_post_type('lunchlearn',$args); 
}
add_action('init','register_lunchandlearn');
```

Comment: Looks like your posts are private somehow. Check that first. Also, check whether your permalink setting is post name or not. Also, you seem to be viewing a draft by the look of your URL structure. First, publish a post and check that as well.

Comment: Bikram - you got me on the right track! I was displaying future posts. I was not aware displaying future posts would only be seen by admins. 

I decided to use a custom field to choose and sort by date. (In this case posts are events.) Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved! I had queried to display future posts, making them only viewable by an admin. I decided to use a custom field date picker to choose and sort by date.

This way my custom post type (which are future help events) can be displayed and sorted.